# Dynamically generate filter from seq of columns and values

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Suppose I have a sequence of columns, and I also have a sequence of same length corresponding to a specific value for each column.

I want to filter a dataframe to when each column is equal to its corresponding value in the seq.

Looping over the columns and iteratively filtering seems inefficient, but maybe I have an unhealthy dislike for for loops since I used to be an R programmer.

Is a for loop the best way to tackle this or is there a nice way to turn the sequences into a column that filters like it should?

Code looks something like:

```
val df = data.frame(a=1:3,b=1:3,c=1:3) //use R syntax here for brevity
val cols = Seq($"a",$"b",$"c")
val vals = Seq(1, 2, 3)
val filteredDf = df
cols.map(case(col, i) => filteredDf = filteredDf.filter(col = vals[i]))
```

Comment: Would be much easier if you supplied a code example: sample data, what you've already tried (e.g. the inefficient solution), and expected output. See http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/

Comment: Understood, code was added

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can map each tuple of column and value into a condition, and then use `reduce` with the `Column.and` function to create a single condition that checks all columns.

Then, use `filter` with that condition:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._

val condition = cols.zip(vals)
  .map { case (c, v) => c.equalTo(lit(v)) }
  .reduce(_ and _)

val result = df.filter(condition)
```

For example:

```
df.show()
// +---+---+---+
// |  a|  b|  c|
// +---+---+---+
// |  1|  2|  3|
// |  1|  3|  5|
// +---+---+---+

result.show()
// +---+---+---+
// |  a|  b|  c|
// +---+---+---+
// |  1|  2|  3|
// +---+---+---+
```